# How to change add cart button text to backorder text while backorder product?

Tags: magento-1.9

i use backorder for some products ut change add to cart text to backorder text 
its apply to all product types & list,product detail,search list page.Also any event to know backorder products before load html?Kindly reply me

Answer (score 1):

For change at Product view page, need to change at addtocart.phtml at catalog/product/view/

check current product has  backorder or not change according to it

```
if($_product->getStockItem()->getBackorders()!=0){
$buttonTitle=$this->__('Backorder');
}
```

Same type logic need for category and search page .to check current product  has getBackorders and change according to it. `If $productObejct->getStockItem()->getBackorders()!=0) then it means backorder` avalibale

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();  
$stockRegistry = $obj->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface');
$stockitem = $stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId(),$_product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

  if($stockitem->getBackorders() == 1):
    $buttonTitle = __('Backorders');
  else:
    $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart');
  endif;

?>
```